# How to upsert a Timestamp using Apache Phoenix in plain SQL

Tags: apache, hbase, upsert, apache-phoenix

We are using Apache Phoenix to interact with our HBase installation. We chose Phoenix because it gives us the capability to add data types to HBase columns and because it gives you the possibility to use plain `SQL` to interact with the underlying database.

Using Phoenix you can declare the type of a table column as `TIMESTAMP` (refer to [this](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#timestamp_type) link). For example, let declare the following table:

```
Create table T1
(
    T1_KEY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    TMSTP TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY (T1_KEY)
);
```

The question is: which is the correct syntax to `UPSERT` a row in such a table using plain old SQL? In which format have you to pass the timestamp value to `TMSTP` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to `UPSERT` a value to a column of type `TIMESTAMP` in plain old SQL, you have to resume the [XML standard date format](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp). Following this format a timestamp value looks like as the the following:

```
2002-05-30T09:30:10.5
```

Then, the resulting `UPSERT` operation to table `T1` will be

```
UPSERT INTO T1 (T1_KEY, TMSTP) VALUES ('0123456789', '2002-05-30T09:30:10.5');
```

Notice that you have to pass the timestamp value as a properly formatted `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I had to prefix the string literal with `timestamp`, which looked like this `timestamp'2002-05-30T09:30:10.5'`

Comment: Which version of Phoenix are you using?

Comment: I'm using Phoenix 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need nanosecond granularity, stick to using DATE type which gives you millisecond granularity with better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will propose to change such types in our Phoenix scripts from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE`. Have we to used the XML standard date format also with `DATE`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the timestamp or date as a number representing milliseconds since epoch. This way, you don't have to format the date string in your application.

Comment: If I was working inside a program written in Java or Scala, you were right. But, here we are discussing the issue to upsert a date/timestamp in a plain old SQL script. Can you pass a long value that represents milliseconds also in a script? And if so, how would you retrieve millisecond representation for a particular date?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPSERT INTO T1 (T1_KEY, TMSP) 
  select '0123456789', current_date() 
  from <some table that exists and has rows in in> 
  limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As rbinnun said, prefixing with `timestamp` worked for me.

```
UPSERT INTO T1 (T1_KEY, TMSTP) VALUES ('0123456789', timestamp'2002-05-30T09:30:10.5');
```